# How to run a bash command or set env variables when VSCode open a workspace

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I want to be able to set a few env variables based on the workspace file I'm opening, preferably, I wish I could set those variables into the code-workspace file itself.

Does anyone knows how I can achieve this?

Example:

I wanna be able to run:
`export MY_FAV_ENV="ItsYou`
So I could use this later, What I already do is a bash file to export this variables and open vscode on the same script:

```
#! /bin/bash

# 1 env
export MY_SDK="/Path/to/SDK"

# 2 env
export MY_BIN="/Path/to/bin"

# Launch VS Code
open "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app"
```

but I would like to have this already set on its own workspace.

Thank you.

Comment: I use [direnv](https://direnv.net/) to do this at the shell level, then it's IDE agnostic.

Comment: hum, thanks for the tip. I will check them, do you know a way to perhaps launch a script triggering it by opening a workspace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figure it out!

[image]

Adding this setting into code-workspace file will pass me the variables I need!