# how to run a pre-configured command when new terminal is created in vs code for only opened folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, .net-core-3.1, vscode-tasks

Actually the problem I'm having right now is same as [Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system in Asp.Net Core 3 - Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119904/process-terminated-couldnt-find-a-valid-icu-package-installed-on-the-system-in).

To solve this,  I need to run `export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1` command whenever I open a new terminal in VS Code. But I don't want this to happen all Linux session but only for specific project.

So far, I've tried launch.json and tasks.json config files. But I couldn't succeeded. If I run `dotnet --version` I'm getting the same error from another stackoverflow questions as I provided link above.

Can you help for this.

```
    {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "core31_invariant",
                "command": "export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1",
                "type": "shell",
                "args": [],
                "group": "build",
                "presentation": {
                    "reveal": "silent"
                },
                "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out. It was all about setting env. variable in `settings.json` inside the **project folder**

Note: This is for only if you especially want to do it for per project *not every folder you open by VS Code*. If you want to make it available for all folders are opened in VS Code, you need to add it this setting to global file not local.

Actually, you can run any command by adding following settings in your `settings.json`

```
    {
        "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
            "BashWithStartup": {
                "path": "bash",
                "args": ["--init-file", "./pre_config.sh"]
            }
        },
        "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "BashWithStartup"
    }
```

and then you need to write the commands in your `./pre_config.sh` file. But for some reason this doesn't work for me.

So I've found another way to get around thanks to Nathan Almeida who asked question [How to run a bash command or set env variables when VSCode open a workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525368/how-to-run-a-bash-command-or-set-env-variables-when-vscode-open-a-workspace)

There is a `terminal.integrated.env.linux` setting in VS Code which you can pass the all variables those you want to make it available for every terminal you open in that particular folder/project you open in VS Code.

To do that add following option in your settings.json file like this:

```
    {
        "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
            "DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT": "1"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've found a solution, but I'd like to point out that you could use [direnv](https://direnv.net/) for your needs.

Basically, you put your env in `.envrc` in any directory and direnv hook will looks for that file up from the current directory by hooking into `PROMPT_COMMAND`. It supports hooks for all the common shells like bash, zsh, tcsh and fish.

Comment: thank you very much. I'm glad to learn that there is a such kind of tool. This is more specific solution with compared mine. This works in a non-VS Code environment as well. Well done.